# Right click causes some OSX apps to maximize

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I'm having a strange problem with my MacBook. I'm currently running Lion, but I got it with Snow Leopard and as far as I can tell it's always done this.

In some applications, when I right-click anywhere, it causes the app's window to become maximized. Examples are Disk Utility and the VMware launcher. Skype used to do it too, but that changed after one of the last major upgrades.

Google tells me I seem to be the only one with this problem and I have no idea what might be causing it. Any hints?

Comment: That sounds weird. Does this happen with trackpad or mouse (or both)? Do you have any software that modifies mouse behavior? (BetterTouchTool et al). What are your settings in *System Preferences* > *Trackpad*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the culprit.  Do you by any chance use an app called SecondBar?  It's an app that adds a menubar to a second screen.  I've found that when I exit it, this problem goes away.

I'm submitting a bug report to the developer, though I think this program might not be actively developed anymore....

Comment: You say you've found the culprit, but you don't even know if the OP has the app installed. Perhaps you should get clarification of the fact before submitting as an answer?

Comment: I no longer have this problem on my new MacBook but I was in fact using SecondBar on my old one so it seems very likely that it was causing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

People tend to use their mac os x apps maximized so they don't notice when this happens.  But yes, it's a very common thing.  It happens in finder when you right-click on a column in detail view.  It has been happening since at least 2006, and it has never been fixed.

I've used five macs since that time that I've noticed this on, and as a member of the vanishing minority that uses their computers in a spatial mode this is very annoying.